# Looping through an array of arrays in PHP to generate only one array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to loop through an array that has two arrays inside, and each one with user id numbers and amounts of money that each owe.

My problem is that I need to loop through every element as if it were one and generate a new array.

**Here's the array:**

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array {
    [1]=>
    array {
      ["u"]=> string(1) "1"
      ["pagoTotal"]=> string(6) "241.01"
    }
    [2]=>
    array {
      ["u"]=> string(1) "2"
      ["pagoTotal"]=> string(6) "110.02"
    }
    [3]=>
    array {
      ["u"]=> string(1) "3"
      ["pagoTotal"]=> string(6) "385.03"
    }
    [4]=>
    array {
      ["u"]=> string(1) "4"
      ["pagoTotal"]=> string(6) "962.04"
    }
    [5]=>
    array {
      ["u"]=> string(1) "5"
      ["pagoTotal"]=> string(6) "568.05"
    }
    [6]=>
    array {
      ["u"]=> string(1) "6"
      ["pagoTotal"]=> string(6) "664.06"
    }
    [7]=>
    array {
      ["u"]=> string(1) "7"
      ["pagoTotal"]=> string(6) "525.07"
    }
    [8]=>
    array {
      ["u"]=> string(1) "8"
      ["pagoTotal"]=> string(6) "699.08"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array {
    [9]=>
    array {
      ["u"]=> string(1) "9"
      ["pagoTotal"]=> string(5) "50.09"
    }
  }
}
```

**So basically I need to loop as if they were 9 elements instead of 8 + 1 in two arrays.**

**I tried a foreach of the main array, to put everything in one array like this:**

```
  foreach ($unidades as $k => $v) {
      $a[$k]['u'] = $v['u'];
      $a[$k]['pagoTotal'] = $v['pagoTotal'];
  }
```

But of course it will loop through the two elements.

Comment: What else have you tried? Is that structure always the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is loop through each record in each of the two arrays:

```
$newArr = []; // If you want to create a new array

foreach( $unidades as $arr ) { // Each of the two outer arrays
  foreach ( $arr as $info ) { // Each of the info arrays
    echo 'Got ' . $info['u'] + . ', ' . $info['pagoTotal'] . "\n";

    // If you want to create a new array:
    $newArr[] = $info;
  }
}
```